# How get return value from Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, web-services, webserver, getter-setter

I am using `Thread` for `Webservice` but i cant get the data from `Thread` because i cant return data from `Thread`.

This is my `WebService.java` :

```
public class Webservice {
    static String result;
    public static String readUrl(final String url) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
                    InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    result = ConvertInputStreamToString(stream);
                    Log.i("xxx","OK" + result);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
            thread.start();
            return result;
    }

    private static String ConvertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputstteam) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputstteam));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is `NotesActivity.java` :

```
public class NotesActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<StructTask> nettasks = new ArrayList<StructTask>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = Webservice.readUrl("http://192.168.200.101:8081/note-server/");
                if (result != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = tasks.getJSONObject(i);
                            //Log.i("LOG", "Task: " + object.getString("task_title"));
                            StructTask task = new StructTask();
                            task.id = object.getLong("task_id");
                            task.title = object.getString("task_title");
                            task.desc = object.getString("task_desc");
                            task.done = object.getBoolean("task_done");
                            nettasks.add(task);

                            for (StructTask taskes : nettasks) {
                                Log.i("LOG", "Taskes: " + taskes.id + "|" + taskes.title + "|" + taskes.desc + "|" + taskes.done);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } 
                else
                {
                    Log.i("OK", "TaskesOK: " + result);
                    Log.i("LOG", "Task: " + "NULL");
                }

            }
        });
        thread.start();

    }
}
```

This is my `StructTask.java` :

```
public class StructTask {
    public long id;
    public String title;
    public String desc;
    public boolean done;
}
```

This code return for me NULL .

Comment: You really don't want to spawn of a new thread in onCreate. This can lead to all kinds of trouble including memory leaks and problems with the life cycle of your appication. What you need to do is check up on the android device AsyncTask.

Comment: you can use sharedprefrences to store the data temporarily or use a static variable and assign the values in your thread

Comment: Why are you not using async for that?

Comment: Be very carefully with static fields (like result) that are overwritten on multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this way

**1) Webservice.java**

```
public class Webservice {
        public interface WebCallListener{
            void onCallComplete(String result);
        }
        public static void readUrl(final String url,final WebCallListener callListener) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
                        InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                        callListener.onCallComplete(ConvertInputStreamToString(stream));
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }

        private static String ConvertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputstteam) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        inputstteam));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                return builder.toString();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**2) NotesActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Webservice.readUrl("http://192.168.200.101:8081/note-server/",new WebCallListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallComplete(String result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = tasks.getJSONObject(i);
                            //Log.i("LOG", "Task: " + object.getString("task_title"));
                            StructTask task = new StructTask();
                            task.id = object.getLong("task_id");
                            task.title = object.getString("task_title");
                            task.desc = object.getString("task_desc");
                            task.done = object.getBoolean("task_done");
                            nettasks.add(task);

                        }
                        for (StructTask taskes : nettasks) {
                                Log.i("LOG", "Taskes: " + taskes.id + "|" + taskes.title + "|" + taskes.desc + "|" + taskes.done);
                            }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("OK", "TaskesOK: " + result);
                    Log.i("LOG", "Task: " + "NULL");
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: @ Biraj Zalavadia . in NotesActivity.java i cant use from WebCallListener. It say me : WebCallListener cannot be resolved to a type .

Comment: Import it man. I have create it in Webservice class. Copy both class

Comment: can you please post full logcat

Comment: Sorry i dont add url in your class .i added the url and work without error but dont show me Log.i("LOG", "Taskes: " +.... in Log cat for result .

Comment: It work without error but i cant see any result. Just has not error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57319/discussion-between-biraj-zalavadia-and-jefferson).

Comment: What you are getting in response?

Comment: For example is : "Taskes: " 1 Titleone descone done1 AND 2 Titletwo desctwo done2

Answer (score 0):

You may use your code some thing like this:

```
private class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myBackgroundImageDownloadFun(param[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPreExecute Called");
        simpleWaitDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImageDownladerActivity.this,
                "Wait", "Downloading Image");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called");
        MyImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        simpleWaitDialog.dismiss();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use AsyncTask i.e,

```
private class Webservice extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<StructTask>> {
    private ArrayList<StructTask> nettasks = new ArrayList<StructTask>();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<StructTask> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String result = readUrl("http://192.168.200.101:8081/note-server/");
             JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(result);
             for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject object = tasks.getJSONObject(i);
                 //Log.i("LOG", "Task: " + object.getString("task_title"));
                 StructTask task = new StructTask();
                 task.id = object.getLong("task_id");
                 task.title = object.getString("task_title");
                 task.desc = object.getString("task_desc");
                 task.done = object.getBoolean("task_done");
                 nettasks.add(task);
             }
             for (StructTask taskes : nettasks) {
                 Log.i("LOG", "Taskes: " + taskes.id + "|" + taskes.title + "|" + taskes.desc + "|" + taskes.done);
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nettasks;
    }
 /* after parsing response this method will be called*/


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<StructTask> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    private String readUrl(String url) throws Exception{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
        InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String result = ConvertInputStreamToString(stream);
        Log.i("xxx", "OK" + result);
        return result;
    }

    private String ConvertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputstteam) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputstteam));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In your activity class in onCreate method try to call like this

Webservice service=new Webservice();
service.excute();

so it will starts the excution of the above thread.

i think this will helps you